# Mongodb: find documents where at least one array element matches?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with the following structure:

```
[{
    "items": [
        {
            "sent_to_lab": 123,
            "received_from_lab": 456,
        },
        {
            "sent_to_lab": 123,
        },
    ]
}
... more orders ...
]
```

I want to fetch all orders where *at least one* item matches the following criteria:

```
'$and': [
    {'items.sent_to_lab': {'$exists': True}},
    {'items.received_from_lab': {'$exists': False}},
]
```

So in this case, I would like to return the aforementioned item, because at least one element of the `items` array matches my criteria.

How can I do this in mongo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the $elemMatch operator:

```
db.collection.find({items:
                     {$elemMatch:{
                           sent_to_lab:{$exists:true},
                           received_from_lab:{$exists:false}}
})
```

This is query $elemMatch - if you only want to get back the item that matched the condition (and not the entire document with the whole array) then you can use the projection $elemMatch operator similarly.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! In this case, I actually want the entire document. But it seems that my existing query is making sure that *all* elements of the array match the criteria, instead of "one or more"

Comment: actually, no that's not how arrays work in MongoDB.  Your query says return any document where any sub-document has sent_to_lab AND any sub-document does not have received_from_lab.  That means your query would return document which has two subdocuments, one with sent and received existing and another with neither(!)  elemMatch combines them so that they are applied to the same subdocument, which is what I understood your use case to be.

Comment: After some fiddling, I see that you are right, and `$elemMatch` is exactly what I was looking for. Very much appreciate it.